# Integrable functions on a field

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{X}$ (not a $\sigma$-field) be a field on a non-empty set $X$ and $B(\mathcal{X})$ be the set of uniform limits of simple, real-valued, $\mathcal{X}$-measurable functions, i.e.
\begin{align}
B(\mathcal{X}) = \left\lbrace f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \ \ \mathrm{s.t.} \ \ 
\forall \epsilon > 0, \ \ \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \ \ \mathrm{s.t.} \ \ |f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon \ \forall n > N \ \ \mathrm{where} \ \ f_n  \ \mathrm{is \ a \ simple, real-valued,} \ \mathcal{X} \mathrm{-measurable \ function} \right\rbrace
\end{align} 
How can I show that any $f \in B(\mathcal{X})$ is integrable against any finitely additive probability on $\mathcal{X}$? I was thinking about using the Dominated Convergence Theorem, however the theorem is state for measurable space, but my space is not measurable since $\mathcal{X}$ is a field, not a $\sigma$-field.

Comment: First you need a definition of "integrable".

Comment: The definition of integrable is that $\int|f| d\mu < \infty$ where $\mu$ is a finitely additive probability measure on $\mathcal{X}$.

Comment: Next, you need a definition of $\int|f| d\mu$.

Comment: The is the Lesbegue integral.

Comment: I do not know the definition of $\int|f|\;d\mu$ for field and not sigma-field.